# Weblogic Proxy-Plugin

Tags: proxy, weblogic, load-balancing

I am new to Weblogic.I was experimenting on the load balancing capabilities of WLS.I used a proxy plugin provided by default as a load balancer.

I want to check which server in a cluster gets the request from the proxy server every time I reload my site.

When I use "request.getServerPort()"  I am getting the proxy server's port, but what I want is the managed server's port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [request.getLocalPort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalPort())?

Comment: Works.what is the diff btw x forwarded port and localport?